# Reduce pagination numbers

Tags: html, angularjs

I have built pagination using Materialize CSS and AngularJS. See the below image.

[image]

I have a controller file which contains an array of objects based on which the number of pages is decided.

Controller.js

```
app.controller("products", ["$scope", function($scope) {
    $scope.products = [{foo: 'bar'},{},{}..{}];
    $scope.currentPage = 0;
    $scope.pageSize = 10; // number of products to show on a page
    $scope.numberOfPages = Math.ceil($scope.prods.length/$scope.pageSize);
    $scope.pages = function(number) {
        return new Array(number);
    }
    $scope.setCurrentPage = function(index) {
        $scope.currentPage = index;
    }
}]);
```

HTML:

```
<ul class="pagination">
    <li ng-repeat="x in pages(numberOfPages) track by $index" ng-click="setCurrentPage($index)" ng-class="{ 'active': $index === currentPage }"><a href="#!">{{$index+1}}</a></li>
</ul>
```

Now, I want pagination to be like the ones shown in the image. First and last page numbers remain always visible but the selected page number is visible along with its neighboring page numbers only. For example, for 2 --> 1,2,3 and for 7 --> 6,7,8 and so on.

Please help.

Comment: Create a custom filter and use it in the <li> where you pass the numberOfPages and x and the filter should consider first page, current page and last page.

Answer (score 0):

I've included a working snippet below, but I'll highlight the salient aspects about it first.

The general idea is to use `ng-show` to show or hide each page link button part of the pagination widget. The logic to do so is based around: the page which the link represents, the current page, and the page link window size (in your case, it's simply one).

The only other tricky part is these ellipses you require. My suggest here is to implement them as pseudo-elements. These pseudo-elements are shown or hidden based on the application of CSS classes which can only ever be applied to the first or last page link items of the pagination widget.

The example is barebones and strips out anything that isn't relevant to getting the pagination behaviour you want.

```js
angular
  .module('app', [])
  .controller('products', function ($scope) {
    $scope.currentPage = 0;
    $scope.pageCount = 100;
    $scope.pageLinkWindowSize = 1;
    $scope.pages = function (pageCount) {
      return new Array(pageCount);
    };
    $scope.setCurrentPage = function (index) {
      $scope.currentPage = index;
    };
    $scope.isPageLinkVisible = function (index) {
      if (index === 0 || index === $scope.pageCount - 1) {
        return true;
      } else {
        return index >= Math.max($scope.currentPage > $scope.pageCount - 1 - $scope.pageLinkWindowSize ? $scope.pageCount - 1 - $scope.pageLinkWindowSize * 2 : $scope.currentPage - $scope.pageLinkWindowSize, 0) &&
               index <= Math.min($scope.currentPage < $scope.pageLinkWindowSize ? $scope.pageLinkWindowSize * 2 : $scope.currentPage + $scope.pageLinkWindowSize, $scope.pageCount - 1);
      }
    };
    $scope.hasPagesAfter = function (index) {
      return index === 0 && ($scope.currentPage - $scope.pageLinkWindowSize) > 1;
    };
    $scope.hasPagesBefore = function (index) {
      return index === ($scope.pageCount - 1) && ($scope.pageCount - 1) - $scope.currentPage - $scope.pageLinkWindowSize > 1;
    };
  });
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
li {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 1em;
}
.pages-after::after {
  content: '...';
  display: inline;
  margin-left: 1em;
}
.pages-before::before {
  content: '...';
  display: inline;
  margin-right: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="products">
  <div>
    <label>
      Window Size
      <input type="number" ng-model="pageLinkWindowSize" min="1" />
    </label>
  </div>
  <ul>
    <li
      ng-repeat="page in pages(pageCount) track by $index"
      ng-click="setCurrentPage($index)"
      ng-show="isPageLinkVisible($index)"
      ng-class="{
        'pages-after': hasPagesAfter($index),
        'pages-before': hasPagesBefore($index),
      }">
      <a href="#!">{{ $index + 1 }}</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/angular@1.7.4/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanks for your solution. but the code didn't work. kindly look into it.

Comment: You're not able to run the code snippet inline here? Do you want to elaborate? It should work, unless you're using a really dated browser (I don't use any ES2015+ features anyway). If you've copy-pasted out the code to your application, then I obviously can't guarantee what you've done is right.